# Does RepoDb have Data Validation like Entity Framework?

Tags: .net, validation

I am working for first time with RepoDb, can someone show the Data Validation possibilities if it exists?!

Entity Framework has pretty good validations:

'''

```
    [StringLength(3)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public SqlDateTime BirthDate { get; set;}
```

'''

I'm looking for alternative on RepoDb...

Comment: There is no data validation in RepoDB. Though, the validation may be implemented via ClassHandler feature, but that is up for release yet.